# Is possible to splice item in firebase database array?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have in my firebase database structure like this:

[image]

I want to delete categories[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vfMv.png), but when I am sending DELETE request to `*.firebaseio.com/categories/1.json` I get:

[image]

I want to change rest indexes in my array to get array without null items.
Is possible after delete `categories[1]` to get new array like this?:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should push your items to firebase and firebase will assign a unique id following timestamps

**From the guide:**

Getting the Unique ID Generated by push()

Calling push() will return a reference to the new data path, which you can use to get the value of its ID or set data to it. The following code will result in the same data as the above example, but now we'll have access to the unique push ID that was generated

```
// Generate a reference to a new location and add some        data using push()
var newPostRef = postsRef.push({
  author: "gracehop",
  title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
});
   // Get the unique ID generated by push() by accessing its key
var postID = newPostRef.key;
```

Source: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html

Answer (score 1):

Firebase doesn't natively store arrays. As you see it instead stores the data in a regular JSON object with "sequential numeric" indexes. When you remove an item from that JSON object, the other indexes are not automatically updated.

You have two options here:

1. Always update the entire array.
2. Use Firebase push IDs for the collection.

Firebase push IDs are Firebase's equivalent for ordered collections. While they aren't as easy to read as sequential, numeric indexes, they have several important advantages. You can read more about them in [this blog post about arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and in this blog post about push IDs.

To generate push IDs through the REST API, add each individual item with a `POST` request.